# Javascript efficient approach for changing inner dom elements of a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a unordered list with 12 list items inside it

```
<ul class="rb-grid" id="list">
   <li class="view view-fifth">
       <div class="mask">
          <h2>Article Name</h2>
          <p>Brief</p>
          <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
       </div>
   </li>
   ...
   ...
</ul>
```

Now what i want is that on page load i have to change the content of these h2 and p tags, now while i can do this by hardcoding every list item, but can anyone tell me a better way to make all changes at once by using javascript or jquery anything....
Now i found something like this in dojo , this will make clear what i want actually -

```
var items = registry.byId("list").getChildren();
array.forEach(items, function(item, idx) {
item.onClick = function(evt) {
};
});
```

I want to do some such thing to change the contents of the h2 and the p tags inside every list items

Comment: I want to change the content of h2 and p tags of each list item on page load.

Comment: what do you want to change it to ???

Comment: I will use php to get contents from database , but i wanted to know if i can do this using javascript if i have values like for the first list item h2 = "hello world" for second list item h2 = "article 2" or something like this

Comment: try to change it by javascript innerHTML or jquery .html()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here for comparison is a more idiomatic jQuery version of Mr_Green's answer:

```
$('.rb-grid').children('li').each( function( i, element ) {
    var $element = $(element);
    $element.find('p').html("change to something");
    $element.find('h2').html("change to something");
});
```

OTOH, you may not even need the loop, depending on what you're doing. If you just want to change all the relevant nested `p` and `h2` elements to the same value, then Tushar Gupta's answer is a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (*jquery*)

```
var lis = $('.rb-grid').children('li');
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length : i++){
    $(lis).eq(i).find('p').html("change to something");
    $(lis).eq(i).find('h2').html("change to something");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A non jquery way:

```
var ee = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName('li');

for(i=0; i<ee.length; i++) {
    ee[i].getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].textContent = "hello world";
    ee[i].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent = "article 2";
}
```

**EDIT**: It seems IE previous to IE9 does not have `textContent` and should use `innerText` instead. Thanks Mr_Green!

Comment: ahh! didn't knew that. In that case I guess it should be used `innerHTML` instead, right?

Comment: no, actually `innerText`. check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.textContent#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 2):

**js**

```
var x =$('.rb-grid').children('li');
x.find('p').html('change to something');
x.find('h2').html('change to something');
```